# TSQL, remove negative values in a group

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with following data:

```
Id  Name    Value
1   John    100
2   John    -500
3   John    500
4   Smith   10
5   Smith   20
6   Smith   -20
7   Stuart  -10
8   Wills   25
```

I am looking for an efficient TSQL query which can remove John -500 and Smith -20 (i.e. records with negative value if they have a similar positive value in the same group [group by names]).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, great job editing

Comment: It's not clear, are you wanting to leave the John 500 and Smith 20 records in the query, or remove both the positive and negative records if the absolute value of it is found?  Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Comment: As above, you are asking to group by name, but John has two values above 0 so which value should be displayed? Do you even need to know a value ? Expected output please

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I think he needs to remove records with negative values if the same user has record(s) with value = ABS(-value). In other words record Ids 2 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. ([SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46e60/1))

```
delete y
from mytable y join (
  select id,name, value
  from mytable x
  where value > 0) z on y.name = z.name and y.value = -1 * z.value 

select * from mytable
--SELECT RESULTS AFTER DELETING
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   John    100
3   John    500
4   Smith   10
5   Smith   20
7   Stuart  -10
8   Wills   25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete a
from mytable a 
join mytable b
  on b.name = a.name
 and a.value < 0
 and b.value = -1 * z.value
```

Almost the same as Kaf +1